# awk processing single line with fields separated by semicolons failing with RS

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file called strg.cfg with the content

```
iMac;1;1;37;;Monitor;1;1;0;;Thunderbolt;1;0;0;;TimeMachine;0;0;0;;USB;1;0;0;;Lacie Stereo;0;0;0;;Rland MacMini;0;0;0;;Scanner;0;0;0;;end
```

The records are separated by two semicolons ;; and the fields by a single semicolon.
I tried to process this file with the following awk file

```
BEGIN {FS=";"; RS="/\;\;/"}
{ print $1 ", " $2 ", " $3 ", " $6 }
```

$6 is used as a test since if it works it shouldn't print anything for that since it's only four fields.
But that doesn't seem to work, as if the RS= is not taken into consideration at all. It will always still see the whole line as the record.
Printing "Monitor" for $6 and not printing other lines.

Comment: There's nothing special about semicolons so you don't need to escape them. The ability to use multiple characters in a RS is gawk-specific though - are you using gawk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the expected output so we're left guessing but is this what you want?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {FS=";"; OFS=", "; RS=";;"}
RT{ print $1, $2, $3, $6 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
iMac, 1, 1,
Monitor, 1, 1,
Thunderbolt, 1, 0,
TimeMachine, 0, 0,
USB, 1, 0,
Lacie Stereo, 0, 0,
Rland MacMini, 0, 0,
Scanner, 0, 0,
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT. If you don't have GNU awk then the simplest solution is to convert the `;;`s to the usual RS (\n) first:

```
awk '{gsub(/;;/,"\n")}1' file | awk '....'
```

but if you'd rather avoid the 2 awk calls and pipe then you can do this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {FS=";"; OFS=", "; RS=";"}
/^$/ {
    $0 = rec
    rec = ""
    print $1, $2, $3, $6
    next
}
{ rec = (rec ? rec FS : "") $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
iMac, 1, 1,
Monitor, 1, 1,
Thunderbolt, 1, 0,
TimeMachine, 0, 0,
USB, 1, 0,
Lacie Stereo, 0, 0,
Rland MacMini, 0, 0,
Scanner, 0, 0,
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't precise enough. I'm on OS X 10.12 and the output by Ed Morton is what I expected but I only get
    iMac, 1, 1, Monitor

I guess it's not gawk on OS X, hence it doesn't allow l´multiple characters in RS :(

Comment: It's not gawk by default on OSX. You should be able to install gawk though - can you?

Comment: I added a couple of non-gawk solutions for you.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. JFYI the reason for this is to see the state of my network controlled socket strip without opening up the browser. Preferably to be able to add this to an AppleScript in the future.
The complete command is "curl --silent --user username:password http://ip-address/strg.cfg | awk -f state.awk".
Thanks again, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Awk combines different commands. When you just want to replace `;;` by a new line before selecting fields, you can do

```
sed 's/;;/;\n/g' strg.cfg | cut -d";" -f1,2,3,6
```

or replace some stuff in the result

```
sed 's/;;/;\n/g' strg.cfg | cut -d";" -f1,2,3,6 | sed 's/;/, /g'
```